# How to get only one instance of a model in views

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am Building a BlogApp and I am stuck on a Problem.

**What i am trying to do**

I am trying to access all the data of only one `Model instance` in `Function Based View`.

**In Brief**

I am trying to show all the posts liked by a `all the users` in a particular page.

**What have i tried**

```
  1). post = Paintings.objects.filter(likes=pk)
```

- This didn't work because it only show the logged in user's posts. AND i want to get all the posts that are liked.

  ```
  2). post = Paintings.objects.all()
  ```
- This also didn't work for me.

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_owner = models.ForeignKey(User,default='',null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='post_like', blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def featured_paintings(request,pk):
    post = Post.objects.filter(likes=pk)

    context = {'post':post}
    return render(request, 'mains/featured_posts.html', context)
```

I don't know what to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Do you want all posts that are liked by atleast one user or do you want all posts that are liked by all users?

Comment: Thanks for Comment, I want all the posts liked by atleast one user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) lookup to filter a relationship having at least one related object

```
Post.objects.filter(likes__isnull=False)
```

Comment: Thanks. That's the Thing

Answer (score 1):

Try excluding Posts that match `likes=None` this will give you all instances who have atleast one like:

```
post = Post.objects.exclude(likes=None)
```

Comment: Thank you very Much, Both the answers worked fine. Can you suggest me what should i tick as `Correct Answer` ?

Comment: @Progam Iain Shelvington's answer he was earlier by a few seconds.

Comment: Thanks, You're vey kind